# Hour validation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, hour

Can someone please tell me how can I tell the user that he must input an hour above `08:30h` and below `22:30h`?

[image]

This code causes an "incorrect syntax" error, and I can't move forward and I don't know why.

I am new to SQL. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: your sql does not have a `where` clause

Comment: Do not add code as images. Paste it in the question.

Comment: Why are you declaring your start/end of day times as strings and not `time`s?

Comment: i used it as datetime before but it also didn't make a difference not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

First use the correct data type. Use `time` instead of `nvarchar` for the time of the day. Then a good way to enforce that the data must satisfy certain rules like being after 08:30 and before 22:30 and start earlier than end or at the same time.

```
CREATE TABLE hours
             (idhour nvarchar(2),
              starthour time,
              endhour time,
              CHECK (starthour > '08:30'
                     AND starthour < '22:30'
                     AND endhour > '08:30'
                     AND endhour < '22:30'
                     AND starthour <= endhour));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=06eb230320fba5c336c55779d3161cda)

Comment: thanks a lot sticky bit but where was i doing wrong in the while loop? that is what i was trying to understand. Where do i put the "where clause" looks like a replier told me so.

Comment: Your whole idea to try to verify the data when it's *already* in the table doesn't make much sense to me...